# Unable to Track Field History of Custom Fields in Custom Objects

Tags: salesforce, custom-fields

I have a custom Object called Billing and a number of custom fields in it. 
What I'm trying to do is enable Tracking Field History so that whenever one of these Custom Fields is changed, the change will show up on the history log. 
So I went to Setup -> Create -> Objects, select Billing from the list of Custom Objects, select Set Tracking History and check the boxes besides the required Custom Fields.

The problem is that only changes in one of these fields show up on the log, while the rests don't.

Any idea what's wrong? Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Are you sure that you are checking the fields for which you have enabled History Tracking in the history log?

It seems to be working properly in my org for any custom/standard object.

Comment: Yeah, I'm sure. In fact I've tested each field individually and only one of them works properly.

Comment: I think more info would be required on this. Could you please share screenshots, object XML, etc.

Comment: I'm just an intern in this company so I'm not sure I can do that. 
I've reported this problem to my supervisor, so ... well thanks for trying Rakesh :)